# Wondering if this would work as a single if() statement

Tags: php, if-statement, strlen

I am working on a registration form, and working on the if statement where it checks if the password matches confirmation password.

What I am wondering is if I can combine the checking of the two passwords to each other WITH a password length checker and to return an error, or continue inserting the user into the database if both pass.

Is this logical or possible to combine the password comparison with the **strlen()** function in the same **if()** statement separated with an **||** or should it be a **&&** in between?

```
        if ($password != $password_confirm || strlen($password) < 8) {
$error_register = 'Passwords do not match or is under less that 8 characters';
        } else {
      //finish inserting user into database statement
          }
```

Or should I just make 2 different statements?

Comment: Looks fine. Did you have a specific problem? Whether to keep what you have or make it two different statements is primarily opinion based. Your question is essentially "Should my two potential invalid outcomes have their own respective message" (a question for [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) perhaps).

Comment: I make two different statements

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com and the code is already working.

Comment: YOu'd need separate if() statements if you want to explicitly mention both problems. But there's nothing wrong with this as-is. But you're basically fishing for opinions, which is explicitly off-topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks for all the opinions and such, I might make it two different statements as @brandelizer suggested, so it would give a separate message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make two different statements if you want to show two different error messages, for example:

```
if ($password != $password_confirm) {
   $error_register = 'Passwords do not match';
} elseif (strlen($password) < 8) {
   $error_register = 'Password is under less than 8 characters';
} else {
   //finish inserting user into database statement
}
```

Otherwise, the code you provide is fine.

Comment: Thank you for the elseif() part, i didn't think about that at all!

Comment: This is what I Went with, I can also probably use this to check if email format is correct and if its taken already by another user

Answer (score 3):

What you have there should work perfectly fine.

The main difference between the two options is that if you have separate statements, you can give a bit more information to the user, telling them that they don't match, or that they are too short. As is, the user will only know that one or the other (or both) is wrong.

If you don't feel the need to distinguish between the two cases, the single statement is a bit more compact.

Answer (score 3):

This is fine from a programming standpoint but not from a user interface standpoint. It's much nicer to return a specific error message for both the 'passwords don't match' error and the 'password too short' error.

Comment: You are right! I will turn it into two different statements separated with a elseif()

Answer (score 2):

It's probably fine as a single statement. The logic here doesn't take much staring-time to understand. Stylistically, it may be better to test for the normal flow first (i.e., that passwords match and are the right length). That's just a subtle way of helping any future readers of the code to understand more easily what's expected here:

```
if ($password == $password_confirm && strlen($password) >= 8) {
//finish inserting user into database statement
} else {
    $error_register = 'Passwords do not match or is under less that 8 characters';
}
```